# Would serving a Next.js app with NGINX remove performance optimization?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, https, server, next.js

I am pretty new with Next.js and react apps in general. I used to make apps with php and apache.

Now, before I serve my Next.js app with NGINX I wonder if I lose the performance optimization from Next.js.
This is what I read from the official docs of Next.js

> Before deciding to use a custom server please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization.

But, does this apply when I serve it on NGINX? If there is not way around how come we are suppose to have an https server without losing performance optimizations?

Comment: Nginx can proxy to a next.js server but for server-side functionally nginx can not do it by itself.

Comment: @ShawnC. I did some research based on your comment, and I guess I can run nginx as a reverse proxy with ssl and that would work as normal, right?

Comment: Yes it should work fine in a reverse proxy setup.